# how to render an array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs

I am writing an application to react. I've created two components. One component is receiving an object from the parent component and I want to render it. This object has several elements, one of them is an array of several objects. I have some problems to render the elements (objects) of this array.
this is the main object:

```
        dishes = {
        id: 3,
        name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
        image: 'assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
        category: 'dessert',
        label:'',
        price:'2.99',
        description:'A delectable',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
    ]}
```

I have no problems reading all elements of the object except the array element. I've tried map method:

```
  const menu = this.props.dishes.comments.map((com) => <li key={com.id}>{com.author}</li>);
```

didn't get any response and faced this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

## Don't render until the value is there

Any time you get `map of undefined` you know that the value before map is called is undefined, in this case the value of `this.props.dishes.comments` is undefined. Don't try to map over something that is undefined because undefined does not have the method `map`

```
const menu = (
  this.props.dishes 
  && this.props.dishes.comments 
  && this.props.dishes.comments.length > 0
) && this.props.dishes.comments.map((com) => <li key={com.id}>{com.author}</li>);
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about it? I find it somehow hard to understand!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render Object using map do following

```
  const dishes= Object.keys(this.props.dishes).map((com) => <li key={com}>{com.author}</li>);
```

for array inside object

```
  const menu = this.props.dishes.comments.map((com) => <li key={com.id}>{com.author}</li>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map function inline of your main component's return statement. Instead of making a new variable that you are then referencing in your html, you can do it all inline.

https://carova.io/snippets/rendering-array-map-in-react

Checking the ".length > 0" of the array is used to make sure there are items in your array before trying to map them.